# Python program stuck on loops

Tags: python

Im reading a file line by line and this is the condition (below) I need to implement in python how do I do that

If line begins with ‘<’
Continue or 
Skip through the lines in the file till the line starts with ‘<’
And then the program can continue

```
keyword = "TrapQueueCounter"

count = 0

LastLine=''


def get_last_date():
    try:
        with open('last_date.txt') as last_date_file:
            last_date_str = last_date_file.read().strip()
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(last_date_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %f')
    except IOError:
        #return a date before anything in the logs
        return datetime.datetime.strptime('1990-01-01 00:00:00 000000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %f')


def set_last_date(t):

    with open('last_date.txt', 'w') as last_date_file:
        last_date_str = t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %f')
        last_date_file.write(last_date_str)


t0 = get_last_date()

for logpath in glob.glob('/*.log'):
    #loop through all the files

    print ('logpath:',logpath)
    with open(logpath, 'r') as logfile:
        for line in logfile:
            line = line.strip()
            if line.startswith('<'): //this is where iam stuck..
                continue
            datepart,_,_ = line.partition('>')
            datepart = datepart[1:]

            date, time, ms, tz = datepart.split(' ')

            year,month,day = date.split('.')
            hour,minute,second = time.split(':')

            year,month,day = int(year), int(month), int(day)
            hour,minute,second = int(hour), int(minute), int(second)
            ms = int(ms)

            t = datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day
                            , hour=hour, minute=minute, second=second
                            , microsecond=ms*1000.0)

            if t < t0:
                continue


            #line = line.lower()
            count += line.count(keyword)

            set_last_date(t)


            if keyword in line:
                message1 = 'Counted %s %s times in %s line' % (repr(keyword), count, line)
                LastLine=line
                print message1
```

The file is being read only if the line is in this format at the beginning date, time, ms, tz = datepart.split(' ').
But I want it to read the line only if the line begins with '<' but if the line begins with anyother character I want it to skip till it encounters another line that begins with '<'..How do I do that.Thanks

Comment: can you post the relevant part of your code? that'll give us something to work with.

Comment: Just posted the codes thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
begin = False
with open(filename, 'r') as fid:
    line = fid.readline()
    if line.startwith('<'):
        begin = True
    if begin:
        do_something()
```